# Bootstrap Modal is transparent - Opacity not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap and Modals atm and have no idea what i did wrong

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCKnC.png

As you see the Modals Content is transparent and it doesn't look good...
So what can I do about that?

```
<div id="changeRPGNameModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Name ändern:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRPGName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRPGName"
                       placeholder="Gib einen neuen Namen ein" autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="containerButtons">
                <button class="floatLeft btn btn-default btn48Percent" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                <button class="floatRight btn btn-success btn48Percent" data-dismiss="modal" id="buttonChangeRPGName">Ändern</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to set opacity on .modal-backdrop(.fade.in) but if i do that, the whole background of my screen goes white
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhqbU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, you have closed `<div class="modal-content">` before content load in it so content is loading outside the modal body and `Opacity not working`, I also added `<div class="modal-content">` for modal title.

```
<div id="changeRPGNameModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">            
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Name ändern:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRPGName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRPGName"
                       placeholder="Gib einen neuen Namen ein" autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="containerButtons">
                <button class="floatLeft btn btn-default btn48Percent" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                <button class="floatRight btn btn-success btn48Percent" data-dismiss="modal" id="buttonChangeRPGName">Ändern</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>      
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeRPGNameModal">Open Modal</button>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2fn097j/)

Answer (score 0):

When working on developing modals...

You should make the modal background transparent not the whole modal content transparent.

The easiest solution is...instead of changing `opacity` value change the background color using `rgba()`.

i.e. instead of doing

```css
background : #000000;
opacity: 0.8;
```

do as

```css
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
```

this solution prevents the modal content from having the undesired transparency effect.